# UML Address Book

Tags: uml, addressbook

I started learning UML lang around 10 days ago and getting lost a lot in all lessions, i try practice by myself more then reading "theory". I found suggestion to look into one old completed Address Book project who is missing 1 CRC card
http://www.cs.gordon.edu/courses/cs211/AddressBookExample/CRCCards.html#AddressBook 
and 1 Class design
http://www.cs.gordon.edu/courses/cs211/AddressBookExample/ClassDesign.html

He also missing "Save as.." diagram but i did it by myself.

Can anyone help me with CRC card and class design or advice me how to do. 
Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately this is no online course. It's "I got exactly this problem and need a solution".

Comment: @ThomasKillian is right, this is not the kind of question to ask on Stackoverflow. Sorry but I flagged it as "too broad". But don't give up using Stackoverflow. To try to help you, the first exercise is simple, CRC cards are quite an "informal" way of defining classes. For example, "assign responsibilities to various classes" means add methods to classes. For the "Allow the user to perform the Add a Person Use Case" responsibility of the "AddressBookController" class, this implies adding a "addUser()" method to the the class. For more informations, you should read the Wikipedia article.

Comment: But anyway, you are on the right track to handle UML the easy way. CRC cards are a viable alternative to sequence diagrams as these do not involve objects interactions. It focuses on analysis and responsibilities identification and does not involve directly the object model. Just give up the theoretical aspect : a method is a way for a class or an interface to assume a responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

1. CRC cards do not belong to UML. You should practice in UML if you want to know UML.
2. It is very bad to define classes BEFORE class diagram creation. What is called classes in http://www.cs.gordon.edu/courses/cs211/AddressBookExample/CRCCards.html#AddressBook is called Components in UML. Do not mix them.
3. The normal UML process for a simple school project is Use case(maybe with State diagram elements) -> Component diagram (maybe developed by deployment and/or communication diagrams) -> Activity/Sequence diagram (if you have some non-trivial algorithms) -> Class diagram. For Android an object or Composite structure diagram could be useful, too.
4. The diagrams have very little natural hierarchy. You can use classes on Use Case diagram, or states in the composite structure diagram. But do not start from that, wait a pair of years for that. At start try to study to use pure diagrams, in order to know how to use them correctly, how to think in their terms. The main and most important and wide-spread error of a UML user is a mish-mash of diagram mix.